# html-код на картинку

Tags: html

Здравствуйте.
У меня такой вопрос: как сформировать html-код на картинку, так чтобы человек разместил ее у себя на блоге. А потом когда я вместо нее загружу на свой блог другую картинку, у него на блоге она автоматически обновилась и вместо старой стала новая?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:
 1. Создаем базу где храним картинки. Структура такая примерно (id | path)
 2. Нужен скрипт на php, который при получении параметра id выдает браузеру нужную картинку.
 3. ТОгда ссылка на картинку будет примерно такая `<img src="www.mysite.getimage.php?id=1">`

Answer (score 0):

ээ. Ну сделай просто тегом < img >, да потом меняй на че хочешь. Это если про единичный случай, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто загружать картинку на блог с таким же именем, то есть заменять её.
Но это не выход :)